# How to handle global exceptions in java spring?

Tags: java, spring, exception, constructor-injection

Currently I am working on a small system to log all the uncaught exceptions and store them into a database for further debugging / development.
To do so I am using an UncaughtExceptionHandler for a specific thread:

```
public class GlobalExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler{

    @Autowired
    private LoggedExceptionService service;


    public GlobalExceptionHandler() {
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        System.err.println("IN UNCAUGHTEXCEPTION METHOD");
        this.service.saveException(new LoggedException(e));
    }
}
```

As you can see the field `service` is injected and when I catch an exception, then I get a NullPointerException because the field is null.

The main problem is the usage of the GlobalExceptionHandler. If I inject using the constructor (like in this code snippet):

```
private LoggedExceptionService service;

@Autowired
public GlobalExceptionHandler(LoggedExceptionService service) {
this.service = service;
}
```

then the field is not null, but then I can not declare it as the exception handler, because I can not autowire it to java-native methods. The call would be:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new GlobalExceptionHandler());
```

Is there a possibility to autowire the handler to the thread method or what would be a good way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it a component and set the default exception handler in an `@PostConstruct` method.

```java
@Component
public class GlobalExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler{

    @Autowired
    private LoggedExceptionService service;


    public GlobalExceptionHandler() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        System.err.println("IN UNCAUGHTEXCEPTION METHOD");
        this.service.saveException(new LoggedException(e));
    }
}
```

This allows you to automatically set the handler as methods annotated with `@PostConstruct` in components are automatically executed on startup.

Making `GlobalExceptionHandler` a spring component also allows to autowire `service` that would never been set otherwise. Anyways, I would recommend you to use constructor autowiring:

```java
@Component
public class GlobalExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler{

    private final LoggedExceptionService service;

    @Autowired // @Autowired is actually not necessary if this is the only constructor
    public GlobalExceptionHandler(LoggedExceptionService service) {
        this.service=service
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        System.err.println("IN UNCAUGHTEXCEPTION METHOD");
        this.service.saveException(new LoggedException(e));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The PostConstruct works really nice. I changed the injection to constructor injection. EDIT: Will accept as soon as I can.

Comment: Lol I was in the process of adding that to the answer.

Comment: Well I guess I was faster =P Thanks man, you made my day :)

Comment: Nice vibes here :-D lifted my mood, thanks